# Java, problems with BufferedReader in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader, printwriter

I'm stuck trying to advance. This while loop seems to hang when receiving lines from a socket.

Here's the server side of the code:

```
out = new PrintWriter(socketcliente.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketcliente.getInputStream()));
//receive and shows client data
            linea = 0;
            while ((buffer[linea] = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(buffer[linea]);
                linea = linea+1;
            }
//asks for a command and sends it to client
            System.out.println("Enter remote command");
            while ((input = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
                out.println(input);
            }
```

and here's the client side:

```
out = new PrintWriter(socketcliente.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketcliente.getInputStream()));
//sends a limited amount of lines to the server
linea = 0;
        while (buffer[linea] != null) {
            out.println(buffer[linea]);
            linea = linea+1;
        }
//receive the command from server, executes and save output for sending to the server
        while ((comandor = in.readLine()) != null) {
            proceso = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comandor);
            pinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proceso.getInputStream()));
            buffer = new String[100];
            linea = 0;
            while ((psalida = pinput.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer[linea] = psalida;
                linea = linea+1;
            }
        }
```

After the server prints the data it receives, it does nothing, nor exit the while loop. Must send data back to the client. I'm using PrintWriter and BufferedReader.

Edited: More complete code to understand what I'm trying. The command execution and output's save runs fine, the problem is receiving the data in the server, it gets all the data, but stops at end and don't exit the first while loop. How can I allow it to exit the loop? I tried sending a null byte from the client after the message, or a "quit text" that the server can understand like:

`while ((buffer[linea] = in.readLine()) != null && (buffer[linea] = in.readLine()) != "quit")`

I'm lost and didn't find how to do.

All these are in try statements.
Nothing works. I'm a beginner, thanks for helping.

Comment: The reader wont return null until you close the socket.

Comment: Your code seems to be very prone to errors in general. We don't know what you're trying to achieve. Such as buffer = new String[100]; may cause overflow unless you're limited to 100 lines.

Answer (score 1):

In your `server side` code the incrementing line you have written for `line` is wrong, it must be corrected as `line = line+1;` so the whole `server side code must look as below

```java
line = 0;
while ((buffer[line] = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(buffer[line]);
    line++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Read string to a StringBuilder instead - less allocations, faster and eaasier:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String aux = "";
BufferedReader pinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

while ((aux = pinput.readLine()) != null) {
     builder.append(aux);
}

String text = builder.toString();
```